# Windows 10 Disk Drive label inaccurate

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, device-manager

My laptop came with a hybrid drive which I later upgraded to a full SSD.  However Windows 10 is now showing the old drive's name rather than the new one.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the drive via Device Manager and running the Hardware Troubleshooter.  Neither picked up that the name is out of date.  The drive itself is correct (this isn't my imagination) since the correct label shows in the BIOS, Samsung Magician, and the Hardware Ids, as shown below.

How can I get Windows 10 to show the proper label?

[image: Disk Drive Properties]

Comment: Nope.  That's the friendly drive (partition) name for the end user -- not the same as how the disk drive identifies itself.

Comment: No, I posted what was wrong.  That is the property details of the drive inside Device Manager.  Notice how the label of the drive in both the header and the top of the body show "SSHD" but the actual drive is the "SSD_850..."

Comment: (@Moab) Btw, I'm assuming you can see the screenshot.  If not I could see how my question might be misunderstood.